# Column 'AuctionStatus' cannot be used in an IF UPDATE clause because it is a computed column

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am developing an Auction site in asp.net3.5 and sql server 2008R2, My Database has an Auction Table that has a calculated column "AuctionStatus" - 
(case when [EndDateTime] < getdate() then '0' else '1' end) 
that gives auction status Active or inactive based on End Date.

Now I want to call a stored procedure that sends email notifications to buyers and sellers as soon as AuctionStatus becomes '0'. For that i tried to create a after update trigger that could call the email notification sp, but i am not able to do so.
I am getting the following error message :-

> Msg 2114, Level 16, State 1, Procedure trgAuctionEmailNotification,
>   Line 6 Column 'AuctionStatus' cannot be used in an IF UPDATE clause
>   because it is a computed column.

The trigger is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAuctionEmailNotification ON SE_Auctions
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    IF (UPDATE (AuctionStatus))

BEGIN

 IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted WHERE currentbidderid > 0
                                      AND AuctionStatus='0' )
     BEGIN
        DECLARE @ID int
        SELECT @ID = AuctionID from inserted
        EXEC spSelectSE_AuctionsByAuctionID @ID         
     END
    END
END
```

Comment: Your code assumes only one record at a time will be updated by the trigger. You should correct that as well.

Comment: Yuck, thanks for quick reply. when [EndDateTime] < getdate() becomes true then the computed column AuctionStatus gets 0 and here i want to fire a trigger that will call the Notification SP. What else i have to check in this trigger. do you need any additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just replace AuctionStatus with the corresponding expression :

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted WHERE currentbidderid > 0 AND [EndDateTime] < getdate() )
```

But, the point is I don't see how your trigger will be "triggered" as [AuctionStatus] is never "updated". Its Value is just calculated whenever you need it.

You could go for a sql job that runs every x minutes and send a notification for each auction which ended during the last x minutes.

Comment: Thanks a lot jbl, do you have any reference for such sql job that runs every x minutes and send a notification for each auction which ended during the last x minutes.

Comment: In your object explorer, go to "SQL Server Agent" => right click on "Jobs" => "New Job..." name your job, create a step that performs your notifications on each ended not already notified auction (calling a stored procedure in your db is better than having a raw query insde your agent.) then schedule your job every x minutes. Beware, you'll need a flag to identify already notified auctions.

Comment: Alright, I will do so and post here. Thanks a lot 'Jbl' and 'Damien_The_Unbeliever'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a real column containing a flag to indicate whether the notifications have been sent, and then implement a polling technique to scan the table for rows where the status is inactive and notifications haven't been sent.

The computed column doesn't really transition from one state to another, so it's not like an `UPDATE` has occurred. Even if SQL Server did implement this, it would be hideously expensive, since it would have to query the entire table for transitioning rows every 3ms. (or even more frequently if you're using `datetime2` with a higher precision)

Whereas you can pick a suitable polling interval yourself. This could be an SQL agent job, or in some service code somewhere, whatever best fits the rest of your architecture.